# Strange blur in FLutter BackdropFilter

Tags: flutter, stack, blur, imagefilter

I try on the Back drop Filter in the Flutter widget but get a strange effect. On the one hand there is a blur, on the other hand the objects retain clear boundaries.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            right: 10,
            top: 10,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Color(0xFFbfeb91),
            ),
          ),

          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 50,
            child: Container(
              width: 90,
              height: 90,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),


          Text('Hello world'),

          Container(
            width: 180,
            height: 180,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),

              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),

                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  // color: Color(0xFF55aaff),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  child: Text(
                    "Flutter Dev's",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 28,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],

      )
```

I here is what I've got. Look at the green square - its bounds are clear, like we have 2 layers^ one is blured, and the other one (at the top) is NOT blured).

[Picture with blur effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08hwK.jpg)

And the same effect with letters  'Hello world'

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You should give blur container position by margin as you are using stack as base widget. As you set postioned in above for two widget from top and left. so above two postined overleaped by blur container layout. thats why you getting blur screen. Try below code it will serve your purpose.

```
  Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left: 10,
                  top: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Color(0xFFbfeb91),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 10,
                  top: 120,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 90,
                    height: 90,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Hello world'),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 120),
                  width: 180,
                  height: 180,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                        // color: Color(0xFF55aaff),
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                        child: Text(
                          "Flutter Dev's",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 28,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black38,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
```

Comment: The same situation. Layers are blured and not blured at the same time. Letters are clear with glow effect.  But I do it in web Emulator (not in device emulator), maybe this is the reason?

Comment: Its working fine in my device ! you may try physical device or android studio emulator! I have added screenshoot image in above answer. please check it..

Comment: But there is no blur effect on your picture. White container doesn't intersect with bottom containers